# Pandas groupby: group by semester

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to group data by semesters but there is no frequency tag available [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)

`2QS` (2 quarters from start) and `6MS` (6 months from start) won't do because they will start in different moments, according to the first datetime in my dataframe. *(Quite counterintuitive and prone to errors, IMHO: I didn't see this issue till I used a different dataset that began in May instead of January...)*

```
from datetime import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()

days = pd.date_range(start="2017-05-17", 
                     end="2017-11-29",
                    freq="1D")
df = pd.DataFrame({'DTIME': days, 'DATA': np.random.randint(50, high=80, size=len(days))})
df.set_index('DTIME', inplace=True)

grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2QS'))
print("Groups date start:")
for dtime, group in grouped:
    print dtime
    # print(group)
```

returns

```
Groups date start:
2017-04-01 00:00:00   <== because my first datetime is in May, 2017
2017-10-01 00:00:00
```

instead of:

```
Groups date start:
2017-01-01 00:00:00   <== I want the semesters referred to the year!
2017-06-01 00:00:00
```

As a possible workaround I created two new columns in my dataframe and then group according to them:

```
      df["year"] = df.index.year.astype(int)
      df["semester"] = df.index.month.astype(int)
      df["semester"] = df["semester"] - 1
      df["semester"] = df["semester"] // 6
      grouped = df.groupby(["year", "semester"])
```

**Is this the only way to to this?**

There are two other little questions, just for the sake of curiosity and not worth an indipendent stackoverflow question:

1. why a tag `W` (end of week) is available, but `WS` (start of week) is not?
2. how to write this in a single line?

   ```
     df["semester"] = df.index.month.astype(int)
     df["semester"] = df["semester"] - 1
     df["semester"] = df["semester"] // 6
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest are [`anchored-offsets`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#anchored-offsets), but for month it missing.

And for second:

```
df["semester"] =  (df.index.month.astype(int) - 1) // 6
```

Or without creating new column:

```
years = df.index.year.astype(int)
semes = (df.index.month.astype(int) - 1) // 6
grouped = df.groupby([years, semes])
```

Comment: @jzrael, Thank you. 

Anchored-offset will group my data in different ways (i.e. from Tuesday till next Wednesday). While I can use YS (year start), MS (month start), QS (quarter start), WS is missing. If I group by W, the correct set of data is returned for each group, but the dateindex for the group is the END of the week. I need to subtract 6 days: not a big issue but confusing indeed.

About the main question, is there a way to group properly by semesters? Strangely enough the frequency tag is missing...

Comment: @AlexPoca - Yes, you are right, I think it is not implemented in pandas yet.

Comment: @AlexPoca - There is similar problem with season - [not implemented yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7454)